# Calculating the most popular categories from table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to get a query which will calculate the most popular categories in descending order.

My SQL TABLES:

**Questions**

[image]

**Categories**

[image]

My problem is the following: how do I calculate the number of questions that are in the "Categories"

Comment: please add your sql code

Comment: SELECT COUNT(IdCategory)
FROM Questions
INNER JOIN Categories ON Categories.IdCategory = Questions.IdCategory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`(to even get the unmatched categories) to join both the tables and use `COUNT` aggregate function with `GROUP BY` clause.

**Query**

```
select t1.`IdCategory` as `Category Id`
, t1.`Name` as `Category Name`
, count(t2.`idQuestion`) as `count`
from `categories` t1
left join `question` t2
on t1.`IdCategory`  = t2.`IdCategory`
group by t1.`IdCategory`, t1.`Name`
order by count(t2.`idQuestion`) desc;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc452a/1)**

Comment: your query return result for only one category
[image](https://imgur.com/4ZG8T5M), but i have in my table more categories.
For example:
General,
Category 1,
Category 2,
...
Category n.

Answer (score 0):

Join the to tables by idcategory and sum(1) or counte() them.